# How to make lightning:fileUpload component required field on flows?

Tags: fileupload

I am using lightning:fileUpload component in flows embedded on community page. I want to make this mandatory/ required so that the user sees an error if they click next without uploading a file. I have tried creating a custom footer component and passing attributes from file upload component to validate but not sure how I can display error. Is there any other way to make lightning:fileUpload required in flows ? Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

I've used a workaround that uses a "Decision" if there is no file attached. If the file ID I am passing through is blank, I have it show a screen that informs them a file is required and then takes them back to the file upload. Hoping they will come out with a way to do this without the workaround!

Answer (score 1):

You might try creating a wrapper component for lightning:fileUpload that exposes a validate method.  The method could check if the user has uploaded anything and return the custom error message.

Here is more info on the validation method: https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/winter19/release-notes/rn_forcecom_flow_validate_attribute.htm

Answer (score 0):

Checking if the ID is blank, null or empty, didn't work for me. Similar to this reddit: https://www.reddit.com/r/salesforce/comments/lffnuv/salesforce_file_upload_in_flow/?rdt=54030

I was able to solve it by getting the count of contentDocIds, and if count of contentDocIds = 0, then do whatever. Here's how I did it:

1. Create a new resource variable with data type `Number` (let's call it *contentDocIds_Count*)

[image: create_var]

2. Add an Assignment element and set `contentDocIds_Count` to Equals Count `{!Your_File_Upload_API_Name.contentDocIds}`

[image: set_var]

3. Add a Decision element, and in it, add a condition that checks if `contentDocIds_Count` Equals 0

[image]

With these threein place, I was able to direct the user to another Screen element prompting them to add the missing files.

[image: flow]